# Variable in echo statement correction

Tags: php, variables, echo

The code below parses ok but is not working, I have tried several versions of how its written and the best i have been able to get is the redirect to work but the PHP variable is not placed in the passed url. I'm having real difficulty in figuring out when/where single quote vs double quotes are needed/used when the code has a lot of combinations of both. Using AJAX or JQUERY etc. etc. isn't an option for me in this case so even though this could be approached differently, please stick with the HTML/PHP code. Thanks in advance.

`echo '<input name="Edit" type="button" value="Edit Product" onclick="location.href=\"add-firearm.php?eval=edit&eitem=.\"$row[SKU]\" " />';`

Comment: Replace &eitem=.\"$row[SKU]\" with: $eitem=\".$row['SKU'].\" - Should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, your `echo` produces:

```
<input name="Edit" type="button" value="Edit Product" onclick="location.href=\"add-firearm.php?eval=edit&eitem=.\"$row['SKU']\" " />
```

You want

```
<input name="Edit" type="button" value="Edit Product" onclick="location.href='add-firearm.php?eval=edit&eitem=$row['SKU']'" />
```

So your `echo` should look like:

```
echo '<input name="Edit" type="button" value="Edit Product" onclick="location.href=\'add-firearm.php?eval=edit&eitem=' . $row['SKU'] . '\'" />';
```

Comment: That produces a syntax error - presumable because the echo statement is enclosed using single quotes. **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in your code on line 1"**

Comment: Adjust his example, you don't have to copy paste the code. Issue is that single quotes don't evaluate php variables while double quotes do. Your initial attempt didn't echo the value of variable.

Comment: @FreshPrinceofSO  Thank you the revision worked. I'll look it over and try to understand what/how I was escaping using the wrong characters.

Comment: @N.B. Yeah, I tried several ways before using single quotes but I just couldn't get the right combination. I knew the string would evaluate right as entered, thats just the point where I gave up and asked for help :)

Comment: @Swodahs - if I may suggest checking PHP's HEREDOC string syntax. It's perfect for cases such as yours, you'll have no worries escaping single/double quotes or mixing them with PHP arrays/variables/objects

Comment: @N.B. I think a heredoc is overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<input name='Edit' type='button' value='Edit Product' onclick='location.href='add-firearm.php?eval=edit&eitem=".$row[SKU]."' />"
```

You forgot the '.''s.